# Skipper file upload directory change when uploaded

Tags: sails.js, skipper

Is there a way to upload the skipper images to a special folder in the disk except in the .tmp folder ?

As the .tmp folder gets rebuild and might remove all the uploaded images I need to to change the upload directory.

Please let me know how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Although this post is not very recent, still I would like post my solution for tumbleweeds out there looking for a solution.

The above solution did not work for me:
file getting uploaded to `.tmp/uploads/..`

**Say I want to upload my file in `\public\`** directory which is in my project root.

I would do something like this:

```
var publicDir = '../../public/';

req.file("filename").upload({
    saveAs:function(file, handler) {
       handler(null,publicDir+"/"+file.filename);
    }
},function whenDone(err,files){
    if (err) return res.serverError(err);
        if( files.length > 0 ){
            res.status(200);
            return res.json({msg:"File saved", data: files});
        }
});
```

And it works. I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
req.file('fileName').upload({ dirName: 'someFilePathToSaveTo' }, function (err, files) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: so is this 'somepath' relative to the .tmp ?

Comment: To answer your question: no. You can use an absolute path using ````path.resolve()````, which takes the root of your application as the starting path.

For example, if you want to upload to a folder directly outside of your app's folder, you can do ````dirName: path.resolve('..', 'outsideFolder')````

Comment: do you know how to minify html on production mode in sailsjs ?

Comment: That's a separate question that should be asked in its own post.